# ymaps 3.0 добавление своих элементов

Tags: javascript, reactjs, яндекс-карты

Перехожу с версии 2.1 на версию 3.0 и не могу найти способа добавить свои собственные элементы. В версии 2.1 это делалось с помощью `yMaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass`, в документации и поискав в интернете ответов не нашел. Максимум что увидел это:

```
const buttons = new YMapCollection()
      .addChild(
        new YMapControlButton({
          text: '+',
          onClick: () => map.update({ location: { zoom: map.zoom + 1, duration: 500 } }),
        })
      )
      .addChild(
        new YMapControlButton({
          text: '–',
          onClick: () => map.update({ location: { zoom: map.zoom - 1, duration: 500 } }),
        })
      )

    controls.addChild(buttons)
```

Но тут не вставить свой элемент, только можно менять текст в кнопке и событие.

Что в версии 3.0 заменяет `yMaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass`?

Comment: Здесь это не нужно. Просто указываете свой DOM элемент. https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi30/doc/ru/ref/#class-ymapmarker

Comment: что касается кнопок, там тоже можно вставить свой html элемент https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi30/doc/ru/ref/#YMapControlCommonButtonProps

Comment: @ВикторКарев спасибо, как я этот пропс не заметил.

Comment: @ВикторКарев хотя это не совсем то, в версии 2.1 я мог создать свой элемент и вставить куда угодно в панель указывать отступы справа, снизу и то в конкретных значениях. Сейчас же только можно указывать стороны. Ну и конкретно свои элементы опять же не понятно как вставлять.

Answer (score 0):

```
const bottomControls = new YMapControls({position: 'right bottom', orientation: 'vertical'});
const element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML = '<span>Кнопка</span>';
bottomControls
      .addChild(
        new YMapControlCommonButton({
          text: '–',
          onClick: () => map.update({ location: { zoom: map.zoom - 1, duration: 500 } }),
          element: element
        })
      );
map.addChild(bottomControls);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я так сделал кнопки для элементов зум, мне по дизайну они подходят.  Но для других элементов не подойдет, так как при такой реализации обертка все равно идет от "Control" со своими стилями, и самое главное, нет возможности точно по пикселям поставить кнопку.